# Struts 1.x upgrade

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, migration, struts

We have a struts 1.x application which is stable and running good with no complaints. However we recently thought of upgrading it.

We basically want to change the UI of the application since it is so old and not user friendly at all. So we are planning to use twitters bootstrap along with java script framework like backbone in front-end.

So my question is can we still have struts 1 as the MVC framework will it be compatible to use with framework like backbone or it worth upgrading the struts as I understand we need to write the rest services to return JSON as most of the application are doing today.

Also since struts 1 is marked EOL is this a strong reason to upgrade?

Comment: I suggest first upgrading from Struts1 to Struts2 and then upgrading the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely going to be worth to upgrade from struts1 to struts2. But my question here is, Still the project is in development environment or maintenance phase? If you are going to use for development, please do switch to struts2. Also It's entirely based on project estimation. You can choose the framework based on this. You can find more information about why you need to move/stay from struts1 from [Struts Official Website](http://struts.apache.org/struts1eol-announcement.html)

Comment: We are in maintenance phase application is 5-6 years old now.. but why can't I move to springs instead of upgrading to struts 2? As springs community seems more promising and packaged with more features than Struts 2.

Comment: Moving from one MVC to another takes lot of time, If you have that you can do. That was good idea too.